# на мобильной версии сайта не работает кнопка добавления в заказ

Tags: javascript, адаптивная-верстка, frontend

добрый день, не работает переключатетль городов и кнопка добавления в заказ (перекидывает сразу в корзину без добавления заказа), но на десктопной версии всё работает правильно.

такие ссылки у кнопок переключателя.

```
<div class="placement js-city-block">
    <div class="counter-unit-label phase-header">Шаг 1. Выбор города</div>
    <a href="#" data-city-id="502" class="placement-item counter-item-toBasket">Москва</a>
    <a href="#" data-city-id="505" class="placement-item counter-item-toBasket __active">Санкт-Петербург</a>
</div>
```

такая у кнопки "в заказ"

```
<a data-basket-item="362" data-basket-float_ratio="" data-basket-ratio="1" data-baskset-_div="bx_basket_div_362" data-basket-props="[&quot;PRODUCTION_PRICE&quot;, &quot;PERIOD_PUBLISH&quot;, &quot;PRICE_PUBLISH&quot;, &quot;PRICE_PUBLISH_OLD&quot;]" data-basket-part_props="N" data-basket-add_props="Y" data-basket-empty_props="Y" data-basket-offers="" data-basket-add_item="Y" data-basket-iblock[id]="13" href="/basket/" class="counter-item-toBasket js-counter-item-toBasket" data-basket-quantity="1" data-basket-period="1">В заказ</a>
```

на мобильной версии как я понял сразу перекидывает по ссылке и скрипт не срабатывает

как это можно исправить?

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/213987) Сделайте пожалуйста минимальный пример, воспроизводящий проблему и внесите этот код **в вопрос**.

Comment: понял, поправил

Answer (score 0):

Лучше бы пример кода, но для избежания перехода по ссылке вместо`<a href="#" />` можно сделать `<a href="javascript:;" />`, тогда при нажатии на нее, точно так же не будет ничего происходить, но и срабатывать не станет.

Comment: нужен код скрипта корзины? мне кажется проблема в различиях между кликом мышки и сенсорным касанием

Comment: @rudolf otto Различий между кликом и касанием нет. Единственное различие в том, что в телефоне не будет :hover работать и все. Но попробуйте ваши заглушки заменить так, как я показал, может дело в том, что оно пытает по ссылке перейти и перезагружает страницу

Comment: попробовал. перехода нет, но и добавления в корзину тоже нет. 

при клике мышкой всё ок, но если в панели разработчика выбрать мобильное отображение, там имитация сенсора -- перестает работать, просто перекидывает по ссылке  или заглушке

Comment: @rudolfotto а как у вас скрипт определяет, какую ссылку нажали? Ставит class="active" или что?

Comment: в первом варианте да, где выбор города. ставит класс. а с корзиной сейчас проверю